# How to add a control in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to add [ImageListView Control](http://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/downloads/detail?name=ImageListView_v10.4_Binary.zip) which I found from [here](http://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/) in myVB.net application. I tried adding the dll file to my project references (and rebuild-ed the project) but it is not showing up in my toolbox.

I'm using VS 2010, Winforms. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add it to your Toolbox you'll have to right click the Toolbox and select "Choose Items".  Select the .dll and then the controls will appear.

Comment: It is not listed under Com Components or .NET framework components but it is listed under project-properties>>references

Comment: Click the Browse button and navigate to the directory housing the  Dll.

Comment: on VS 2012, must i do this every time i reopened my project? Is there no way so that it could always appear on project opening?